# How do I echo all the related info using an id from the previous page

Tags: php, mysql, echo

How do I echo all the related info using an id? The id was grabbed from the previous page. There are three columns in my db(id,pageurl,pagecontent). Is my little code wrong to do the task?

```
<?php

include('connect.php');

$id = $_GET[id];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM searchengine WHERE id='$id' ");    

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $pageurl = "$row['pageurl']";
        $pagecontent = "$row['pagecontent']";
    }

echo "$id  ";
echo "  <h2> <b>Details</b></h2> <br/>  $pageurl <br/> $pagecontent";

?>
```

Comment: Oh dear first time here.Here is the code.Dont know where to post what.


<?php

include('connect.php');

    
    $id = $_GET[id];
    
    
    
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM searchengine WHERE id='$id' "); 
    
    
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

   $pageurl = "$row['pageurl']";
   $pagecontent = "$row['pagecontent']";
 }
echo "$id  ";
echo "  <h2> <b>Details</b></h2> <br/>  $pageurl <br/> $pagecontent";

            
?>

Comment: What you have posted is not valid code at all. What are you trying ? be more clear please

Comment: <?php include('connect.php'); $id = $_GET[id]; $query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM searchengine WHERE id='$id' ");  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){ $pageurl = "$row['pageurl']"; $pagecontent = "$row['pagecontent']"; } echo "$id "; echo " <h2> <b>Details</b></h2> <br/> $pageurl <br/> $pagecontent"; ?>

Comment: Funny ? yes yes yes .. you not escaping input(or using prepared statements) while querying a database. Rectify that for sure.

Comment: I have posted an answer below @kmw ... see if it helps and format the question properly please. Let me know :)

Comment: ok...thanks appreciate your response

Answer (score 2):

Based on the code .. the things i can spot are:

1. `$id = $_GET[id]` should have `$_GET['id']`
2. Escape your input while querying a database or use  [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). Or else your in for an **sql injection** sir !!

Comment: +1 for escaping inputs. (but you have a typo in your answer: `is` should be `id`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have the `echo "  <h2> <b>Details</b></h2> <br/>  $pageurl <br/> $pagecontent";` within the while-loop if you want every row to be displayed. Otherwise it will just echo the last values of `$pageurl` and `$pagecontent`.

Also: The 'mysql_' functions is being [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php), so please consider using something else.
Here's a tutorial for PDO, which will help you create more secure database connections: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html